# TypeScript doesn't allow valid union type for React component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, union-types

I've created a functional component that looks like this:

```tsx
type RootComponentProps = {
  propThatAlwaysExists: string;
};

type ComponentPropsV1 = {
  type: "v1";
  onlyOnV1: string;
  onlyOnV2?: never;
};

type ComponentPropsV2 = {
  type: "v2";
  onlyOnV1?: never;
  onlyOnV2: string;
};

type ComponentProps = RootComponentProps & (
  | ComponentPropsV1
  | ComponentPropsV2
);

export const Component: FC<ComponentProps> = ({
  propThatAlwaysExists,
  type,
  onlyOnV1,
  onlyOnV2,
}) => {
  // do typechecked things, no errors in component body
};
```

The `prop?: never` type is a hack I'd learned to be allowed to destructure props, as TypeScript forbids direct access of any property not ***definitely guaranteed*** to exist, but destructuring is the preferred prop access method for code correctness tools like `eslint`, and in my opinion, code readability in general.

I'm then trying to mount this component in its parent, which passes most of these props through. I'd originally tried writing out the parent explicitly:

```tsx
import { Component } from "./Component";

type RootParentComponentProps = {
  label: string;
  propThatAlwaysExists: string;
};

type ParentComponentPropsV1 = {
  type: "v1";
  onlyOnV1: string;
  onlyOnV2?: never;
};

type ParentComponentPropsV2 = {
  type: "v2";
  onlyOnV1?: never;
  onlyOnV2: string;
};

type ParentComponentProps = RootParentComponentProps & (
  | ParentComponentPropsV1
  | ParentComponentPropsV2
);

export const ParentComponent: FC<ParentComponentProps> = ({
  label,
  type,
  onlyOnV1,
  onlyOnV2,
}) => {
  // some effects, yadda yadda

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{label}</span>
      <Component
        propThatAlwaysExists={propThatAlwaysExists}
        type={type}
        onlyOnV1={onlyOnV1}
        onlyOnV2={onlyOnV2}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

But I got a very strange error:

```
Types of property 'onlyOnV1' are incompatible.
  Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
```

I thought this might be because TS was unable to be certain of the identical exclusions between the types, and realized I could DRY up my code some, so I changed `ParentComponent`'s type definitions to this:

```tsx
import { Component, ComponentProps } from "./Component";

type RootParentComponentProps = {
  label: string;
};

type ParentComponentProps = RootParentComponentProps & ComponentProps;
```

However, the error remained unchanged.
At this point, I thought the problem might be that TypeScript effectively loses the context of the exclusivity of the properties, and/or that the strictness of `never` ***really means*** `never`, so I've created an impossible arrangement of props by specifying both `onlyOnV1` and `onlyOnV2` when the union type I've created effectively says that only one of those properties can ever exist.
To combat this, I tried changing the exclusive types of `Component` from

```tsx
type ComponentPropsV1 = {
  type: "v1";
  onlyOnV1: string;
  onlyOnV2?: never;
};

type ComponentPropsV2 = {
  type: "v2";
  onlyOnV1?: never;
  onlyOnV2: string;
};
```

to

```tsx
type ComponentPropsV1 = {
  type: "v1";
  onlyOnV1: string;
  onlyOnV2: undefined;
};

type ComponentPropsV2 = {
  type: "v2";
  onlyOnV1: undefined;
  onlyOnV2: string;
};
```

but again the error remained unchanged, and this is where it stops making sense for me. As far as I can tell, these things are true:

- TypeScript knows from the type of `ComponentProps` that `onlyOnV1` and `onlyOnV2` have inversely exclusive types, where if one is a `string` the other must be `undefined` and vice-versa
- The type passed through from `ParentComponent` to `Component` is ***exactly*** the type of `ComponentProps`

Yet somehow, TypeScript has invented a scenario where the exclusive union type broadens from

```tsx
{
  type: "v1";
  onlyOnV1: string;
  onlyOnV2: undefined;
} | {
  type: "v2";
  onlyOnV1: undefined;
  onlyOnV2: string;
}
```

to

```tsx
{
  type: "v1" | "v2";
  onlyOnV1: string | undefined;
  onlyOnV2: string | undefined;
}
```

for the purposes of type checking against `ComponentProps` even though it literally is `ComponentProps`.

Am I using and/or designing my union types incorrectly?
Is there any way for me to make this work without sacrificing the explicitness of `Component` or `ParentComponent`?

Answer (score 2):

Typescript does what is expected; since you destruct the props, `type` can be `v1` or `v2`; that's why you get the error. There are two options:
Option 1, don't destruct `props` and pass the whole object:

```
<Component {...props} />
```

Option 2, check the value of `type` explicitly:

```
{type === 'v1' ? (
        <Component
          propThatAlwaysExists={'propThatAlwaysExists'}
          type={type}
          onlyOnV1={onlyOnV1}
          onlyOnV2={onlyOnV2}
        />
      ) : type === 'v2' ? (
        <Component
          propThatAlwaysExists={'propThatAlwaysExists'}
          type={type}
          onlyOnV1={onlyOnV1}
          onlyOnV2={onlyOnV2}
        />
      ) : null}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQNwBQrMAnmEohBDELVIAOyQiYABSpgAznAC8uVnDhgZAFQAWKGAEEANgHcUnWQFEAHsFkxZALji2owEQHM2JNh268h4CDEJaQg5ADUARkVlVS4eR1oANwiWFThAg04AeRFIx2dXDzSM7NyAJgB+RzFEpChPbzi-YUDxKRlZMLLonDSmhMSy1NUSnMiquBq6thGRTLGy-JgXdwb2Jrh-UTaQuWiEfkEWoPbQ+QAyOAAKLdbgjsi4AB9N452HsoBKbyRLSFg4GhArZXgETo4iAAeW4nXayAB80SuvVU6lC2l0hhMZisNjsmD6vgJs3muQixPSc1KXQJJE+ikRKLgDBgAFcoCJJqyDAY1j4eHwBJIUAwJDD3mcemkDCgAEZIAxLFZFVGaHT6YymCzWWwOJzLQp8jbC0VHMES8JRJRM-p0ZLDSmkvL65UzR3UyrVJC1eqsLzrXxwE1tcX3M5dKWxXwDIZu0ZkiZTX0kj1Kw1+xqB4Nit5hvZKA5CkUh3OnPbnNJXbNm7Z5zpRF7V0NlzpfH5-aDwIEiEFN0sQwiQvvmuuIpRXNFyekKRlpbsgvAy+UGbBNbDxyLrqkLUjRSeybyqFnszlXNKqSEAE2AiXh59UcEhsjAKBE8JwS4VJEhAHpn6+73vVQcB-AAqOAskkDQAEksgAOTgCJHEvQJaHgS8kGcVkMDgGAtF4fc4FAn8SCAx9m1wAA6aj9zIH9AIfB8QPAyCYPguBFkBfC0AAa1w-DcMDEBX1ZFAeU4IiSLInANgUOS7RSOAKmuMiL2bVSH0nDENWxbU8VkBQcFoLT1SxLVcV1WhSMYmzBJ4Qymms2yHw3CJDNcpznPdBZ3O3cpPJs+iyPpRxZPkpIhiUlSvOhUsNNVdFTM1HEdTsQzjLVTFkr0yyAtspoHN8PKbNc3ynQiYrGI3Moyo9Sq4CC2yQq5HkAt-a9bzSb4M1YIA)

Answer (score 0):

After attempting [wonderflame's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76269776/14695280) without success, I realized that my "minimum reproducible example" was in fact oversimplified - not pictured here was an interstitial use of the TypeScript builtin `Omit<T, U>` type, which allows you to strike keys from an object.

`Omit` had been responsible for the type-broadening because it seems that composite types get combined together when simple object mapping types are run over them. To fix this, I had to be more explicit about my `Component` props as they're passed through from the parent, ***and*** spread the props intended for Component, changing this -

```tsx
type ComponentPassthroughProps = Omit<ComponentProps, "strickenKey">
```

to this

```tsx
type ComponentPassthroughProps = RootComponentProps & Omit<
  | ComponentPropsV1
  | ComponentPropsV2,
  "strickenKey"
>
```